# Changing the char *variable = {"1","2","3"} indexing

Tags: c, indexing, char

So I'm way rusty at C these days.

I know how to create a list of strings within a char* array but is there a way to re-map the list so the first string is indexed as 1 and the second string is indexed as 5?

Here's how I'm trying to use it...

I have a clock program that returns the AM/PM value as 0x00 or 0x40`myclockTimeStruct.RTC_H12` (using the STM32f4xx chip) inside a structure.  I have a `char* AM_PM= {"AM","PM"};` variable.

I don't want to do if statements which I'm currently doing.  Ideally I want to re-index the PM to position 0x40 so it becomes more streamed lined when reading the code.

I seem to recall that it can be done but I can't remember where I saw it.  Maybe it's a different thing I'm thinking of?  I suppose I could always put 63 commas into the brackets but I thought it could be done differently.

Comment: Alternatively, shift left by 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I think you are asking for. The other suggestions are good too.

```
char * AM_PM[0x40+1] = { "AM", [0x40] = "PM" };
```

Comment: That's a fair amount of memory wasted to avoid one `>>6` instruction on each access.

Comment: @R.., I agree, but that's the syntax he asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
AM_PM[rtc_h12 == 0x40 ? 1 : 0]
```

(This could be rewritten to be shorter, but IMO less readable.)

Comment: I forgot about that method...as I said I'm rusty.  It's way clever in "I know what I'm doing" sort of way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing

```
AM_PM[rtc_h12 >> 6]
```

That is, efficiently divide by`0x40` giving either `0` or `1` which can index into your original two-element array.

If there is any doubt that `rtc_h12` could return anything other than `0` or `0x40` then you could do

```
AM_PM[(rtc_h12 << 6) & 1]
```

Masking off the lower bit, and thus guaranteed to get only `0` or `1`.